# String Comparison In MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to compare two strings in MySQL irrespective of the order of two strings:

Here is an example, Say i have a string as 'A1,B1,C1' and i wanted to find out how many rows are there  in table where the column value contains the same string. This can be done easily with like query as given below:

```
select count(1) as attr_count from attribute_lists where attr_tab like :value_names;
```

I will execute this query from PHP using PDO and the string 'A1,B1,C1' will be binded to value_names. However what i also want is if any row contains the same set values but in different order then also they should be considered in count. Say if there is a row with column value as 'B1,A1,C1' then that should be matched and counted as 1.

Irrespective of the order in which the strings are they should be matched. Any help on how can i write such a query?

Comment: it sounds like poor db normalisation if your storing A1,B1,C1 in a single cell. Fixing that would be my staring point

Comment: ...or no normalization at all..

Answer (score -2):

```
select count(1) as attr_count from attribute_lists where attr_tab like '%'+value_name'%'
```

Comment: so you copied a line fro his question, which you clearly did not read